# How to store files in client machine?

Tags: java, file, store

```
File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+"\\Desktop\\" + svc);
        dir.mkdir();
        File f;
        f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+"\\Desktop\\" + svc
                + "\\" + logFile + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis()
                + ".txt");
```

I am using this code to store the files in the user(client) machine.But it is storing   the   files in the server machine.Can anyone help me on this? I have deployed my war file in unix server.

Comment: Can you provide more information on this? It's very unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I need to store the file on client machine. Here i am creating a directory in client machine then storing the file into that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving a file on a client machine from software running on a server is not as simple as that.

Servers do not have direct access to the file system of any client - it would be very insecure if that were the case.

The simplest way to do this is by making the server return a web page with a link which the user can click to download the file.

You could also do something more complicated, for example write an applet that downloads the file (using some file transfer protocol) and saves it in the local file system. The applet would need to have the appropriate permissions (by default, applets cannot access the local file system).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this code is part of a Web Application Server Side. In this case `System.getProperty("user.home")` will return Server's home directory.

Comment: how can i get client's home directory?