# Get local path of my desktop

Tags: java, windows-server-2008

I have installed TOMCAT in Windows Server and there I have deployed a web application. In some point I want to save a file to the desktop and I use

```
File desktopDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop");
```

to get the path.. But this path is the path for the desktop of the server and not mine (when I run the app from my pc). Is there a way to get the path for my pc?

Answer (score 0):

You provided built in System Property "user.home", refer [System Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html). Hence it will always return you the path of the server. if you need to provide dynamic path irrespective of your server, you will need to create custom .properties file which will contain path of the location where you need to save the file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.

You are running your application in the server and saving a file to your local desktop cannot happen in the same way that you can save file to the server desktop.

Maybe you can have this file saving logic in your client(browser or applet) which can then actually download the file from the server and save it in your local desktop.

Even if you do some custom properties for giving the local Desktop location, you still will have to take care of how the actual "streaming" of data happens from the server to your local machine. Its not simple.

Check out this link in stackoverflow which answers almost the same question:
[How to store files in client machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652986/how-to-store-files-in-client-machine)